# BBWC Parts for Proliant DL380 G5 / HP Smart Array P400

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, hardware, bbwc

I have a **Proliant DL380 G5** server with **HP Smart Array P400** controller, the performance of the disk I/O is bad lately and I found out that during my research that I can improve it by enabling the write cache memory on the HP Smart Array P400 controller.

I also found out that in order to keep the data on the disks attached to the array safe in case of power failures or server hang-up, I will need to add a **battery-backed write cache (BBWC) module**.

I looked up the Smart Array spare part numbers **[here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?prodSeriesId=434812&objectID=c00707372#A1)**, but I got totally lost:

- The memory boards read that there are 512 and 256 MB modules, is it safe to **install the 512 and forget the 256 one**? Knowing that my array have 256 MB total cache size in it.
- I would assume that I need the **Battery Cable and Battery Pack** to be installed with with the memory board. Correct?
- I couldn't find anything to show how the actually installation is done (**step-by-step**), can you provide any known link to do the job?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not good enough with parts to know what you have and what you need but installation is very simple. The flash looks like a chunky stick of RAM and will only fit one place on the board. Then, the battery has a long wire attached with a 3 pin adapter which connects the flash. You really can't go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a 405148-B21, the 512MB one, yes it's safe and yes you need the cable and battery.

For instructions it's page 20 of [THIS](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00572169/c00572169.pdf).